# Modify element(s) in a list where a condition is true

Tags: scala, functional-programming, combinations, higher-order-functions

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, qualified: Boolean = false)

val people: List[Person] = ....

val updated: List[Person] = people.map(person => 
  if (person.age >= 25) 
    person.copy(qualified=true) 
  else
    person  // unmodified
))

// Setting every person above 25 y.o. as qualified
```

Is there a combinator/higher-order-function way to do this? Like:

```
people.updateWhere(_.age >= 25, _.copy(qualified=true))
```

It's like a conditional `map`. Most elements pass through unmodified, but those elements who satisfy the condition are modified/"mapped-on".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such thing, although you can make it through implicit conversion:

```
implicit class ListOps[A](self: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def updateIf(predicate: A => Boolean, mapper: A => A): List[A] = {
    self.map(el => if (predicate(el)) mapper(el) else el)
  }
}
```

Test:

```
@ case class Person(name: String, age: Int, qualified: Boolean = false)
defined class Person
@  val people = List(Person("A", 3, false), Person("B", 35, false))
people: List[Person] = List(Person("A", 3, false), Person("B", 35, false))
@ people.updateIf(_.age >= 25, _.copy(qualified=true))
res3: List[Person] = List(Person("A", 3, false), Person("B", 35, true))
```

Comment: Please at least make it `extends AnyVal` to avoid the runtime overhead

Comment: Thank you, I usually remember about that. But what do you mean by "at least"?

Comment: Yeah, that will work. But you'll have to remember to import the implicit everywhere you want to use this pimp'ed method. I'm just a little surprised there isn't a combinator for this -- there's so many combinators.

Comment: If you forget compiler will remind you :p I needed something just like this many times and had no luck finding standard library solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it's just a standard `map`. I'd go with a simple approach like this:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int, qualified: Boolean = false)
defined class Person

scala> val people = List(Person("John", 25), Person("Frank", 30))
people: List[Person] = List(Person(John,25,false), Person(Frank,30,false))

scala> def qualifyIf(p: Person)(pred: Person => Boolean) = if (pred(p)) p.copy(qualified = true) else p
qualifyIf: (p: Person)(pred: Person => Boolean)Person

scala> people.map(qualifyIf(_)(_.age > 25))
res1: List[Person] = List(Person(John,25,false), Person(Frank,30,true))
```

Of coures, you can scope `qualifyIf` into the `Person` companion object, or even to the `Person` case class itself, if you wish.

There might be something exactly like what you're looking for in [cats](http://non.github.io/cats//index.html) or [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz), but unless you already use those libs, it wouldn't be a good thing to introduce them just for this.